# Collide method doesn't change color of shapes

Tags: java

ive made a circle collision method , if it's colliding it will be changing color. but my code seemed dont work. it is changing color even when it is not colliding. this is the code:

```
public class Box extends Rectangle {
    
    Color Color;
    public double radius;

    Box(int x ,int y ,int width ,int height, Color color){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
        this.radius =(height*width)/2;
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color);
        g.fillOval(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
```

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

    public void circleCollision(Box c0,Box c1) {
        if(distance(c0.x,c1.x,c0.y,c1.y) <= c0.radius + c1.radius) {
            Player.Color = Color.BLUE;
            System.out.println(Player.radius);
        }
        else {
            Player.Color = Color.BLACK;
            System.out.println(distance(c0.x,c1.x,c0.y,c1.y));
        }

        
    }

    private double distance(int x0, int x1, int y0, int y1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        float  dx = x1 - x0;
        float dy = y1 - y0;
        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is fine bro, no shame. One thing that i've noticed you maybe should give your variables a more specific name

Comment: well its my first time asking on here though

Comment: A circle is round by definition but in your code the height and width can be different, so either this should be fixed or you are using elliptic shapes rather than circular shapes and then your radius comparison will not work

Comment: radius represents half lenght of the circle

Comment: Note that `Box` is not the best name for a class that represents a circle, you might want to change that to avoid confusion. Also passing `width` _and_ `height` for a _circle_ doesn't make sense since those could be different and thus would define an oval which needs a more complex collision detection method. You might want to pass `radius` instead and calculate `width` and `height` as `2 * radius`.

Comment: well the graphics doesnt have the circle drawing method , it has only fill oval ,with parameter of The height and width

Comment: More importantly: your question title is what people see first, and what gets them to click it ... or not so much. So **only** put relevant things into that. Dont apologize, dont tell us (or yourself) that you are bad at coding. See [mcve], that is what should guide you how to write up such questions.

Comment: i thhougt the other block of code doesnt need so i didnt put that in here , if you want so ill put it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to represent a circle then name the class as such

```
public class Circle extends Rectangle {
```

Then remove either width and height as arguments to the constructor and use the one you keep to set both instance variables. Also note that the radius calculation was incorrect, multiplying is used for area calculations, so the radius was way to large

```
Circle(int x ,int y ,int width, Color color){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = width;
    this.radius = width / 2
}
```

With this I believe your `circleCollision` method should work

Comment: i think i should learn the math more . thx btw it works

Comment: @GhostCat Okay, i Will fix my behaviour
Thx for reminding.